# c++ string :: npos is it calling the string class?

Tags: c++, string

I am new to C++, moving from Java and wondering about this:

```
        pos = result.find(remove[i]);  
        if (pos == string::npos)
```

is it calling the string "superclass"? I am confused if it is calling the class itself accesing the constant "npos" how does it know which instance of the class it is if I have several string variables declared in my function?

Comment: In Java the equivalent would be: `String.npos ;` or `new String().npos`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npos` is not bound to an instance, but to the class itself. It's a `static` member. There are `static` members in Java as well.

#### 21.4 Class template basic_string [basic.string]

[...]

```
namespace std {
template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>,
class Allocator = allocator<charT> >
class basic_string {
  public:
    //...
    static const size_type npos = -1;
    //...
};
```

`std::string` is a **specialization** of `basic_string`.

Comment: Just to add, static members of a class can be accessed in either way -  class::static_member or class_instance.static_member...

Comment: And that's also true in Java, much to the chagrin of anyone who ever called `some_other_thread.dumpStack()`, or a few other static methods of `java.lang.Thread` that act on the current thread.

Comment: So basically this is just like saying if (pos == -1)?

Comment: @TomLilletveit basically, yes. You should still use `npos` though.

Answer (score 2):

`npos` is static member of string.
Static members in C++ are created once per program and are shared by all instances of the same class. but also accessible without instantition of the class.